# Combining line segments into single line in Google Earth Pro

Tags: export, kmz, google-earth-pro

In Google Earth Pro I have a KMZ for a single route, but its segmented into many line segments.

I need to be able to export this KMZ as a single feature - one line for the whole route.

Am I able to combine all the segments into a single line in Google Earth Pro and, if so, then how?

Answer (score 2):

Earth Pro does not have the functionality to combine multi-part line(s) into a single-part line.  If it's sufficient, in Earth Pro you can put all of the lines/segments into a folder and share that as a single KML file.  If you really need them combined into a single linestring, then you'll need to do it in other software.  GIS packages like QGIS have tools to do things like this.  Or if it's a relatively small/simple line, and you're familiar with hand-editing KML, then you could also do it by editing in a text editor, or using find/replace to combine the segments.

Answer (score -1):

Though not in Google Earth for kmz, but [here](https://regex101.com/r/Db4r9O/1) is an example how it can be done on a kml using regular expressions.